# Passing image data to client-side for JS image URL parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, image, code-behind

I have image data stored in a database. I want to retrieve that data in the code behind and pass it to the aspx page so it can be used as a parameter in some JS.

Normally, I would just include a hidden field in the HTML and fill it with whatever data I want on page load from the code behind and then grab it in the JS. **The problem is that the JS function requires an image URL and not a `Byte()` which is how the images are stored in the database.**

How do I convert the image data into something the JS can use?

Here's the JS function for reference:

```
function onVrViewLoad() {
    var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        image: 'images/myImage.jpg', //image URL goes here
        width: 800,
        height: 700,
        is_stereo: false
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 - The issue is that the image data is stored as bytes in the database and has no direct filepath to give to the JS. The JS function needs a filepath.

Comment: make `url` in `image: url,` point to your server-side page (ASP.NET Forms) or controller action (MVC) and return file stream in response.

Comment: What do you mean by "stored as bytes"? You can create a `Blob URL` from a `Blob` representation of bytes stored in database, set `Blob URL` as path to image. You are able to get binary data from database, yes?

Comment: @Igor - That sounds reasonable. Do you have a code sample I could use as a reference?

Comment: @guest271314 - I mean that the image was converted to a `Byte()` and inserted into the database. It has no URL because it's stored in a database. When I want to display the image later, I use a `Select` statement to retrieve the data from the database. So I'm left with a `Byte()` containing the requested image, stored as a variable. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question, there is no URL.

Comment: Well, the majority of data stored within computers are a series of bits or bytes. You can create a `Blob URL` from an `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` representation of the raw data which is stored at a computer or storage facility. That is, how do you retrieve data from the database?

Comment: I just Googled "Blob URL" and this may actually be helpful. I didn't know you force a browser to generate a URL. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Igor - Your solution ended up being the correct one for me. If you can throw your comment into an answer with some sample code, I'll accept it.

Comment: @guest271314 - Your answer was helpful and would have worked for me but the JS library I'm working with is VR View and it has serious issues with cross-origin resource sharing. Apparently blob object URLs are treating as cross-origin by VR View so I couldn't use it. I'll upvote an answer if you want to create one with some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Igor in the comments, I created a separate page that returns the file stream in the response:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rs As SqlDataReader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connString"), "spGetAttachment", Request.QueryString("id"))
    rs.Read()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Expires = 0
    Response.ContentType = rs("ContentType")
    Dim File() As Byte = rs.GetValue(8)
    Response.BinaryWrite(File)
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Then on the original page, I call set the image's URL to my newly created Viewer.aspx:

```
function onVrViewLoad() {
    var imgID = document.getElementById("<%= hfImgID.ClientID %>");

    var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        image: "AttachmentViewer.aspx?id=" + imgID.value,
        width: 780,
        height: 580,
        is_stereo: false
    });
}
```